# dectlaration of function that returns dictionary in Cython

Tags: dictionary, cython

In Cython I can declare a function that **returns an integer**:

```
cdef int fx(int myInt):
    return myInt
```

Same with all datatypes documented [here](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/language_basics.html).

A function that **returns an array of integers** as:

```
cdef int[:] fx():
   ...
  return myIntArray
```

Is it possible to declare a function that **returns a dictionary**? How?

Thank you!

Disclamer: I am new to cython. Please comment or edit my errors.

Answer (score 0):

At least for calling the function from python, is **`dict`**

e.g.
Dict.pyx

```
# function can be called in cython
cdef dict print_dict():                                                         
    cdef dict a                                                                 
    a = {'a':'areli', 'b':'asdasd'}                                             
    return a                                                                    
                                                                                

# function to be called in python                                                                            
def test_dict():                                                                
    return print_dict()
```

In python:

```
import Dict                                                                                                                                                                         
Dict.test_dict()
```

gives:

```
{'a': 'areli', 'b': 'asdasd'}
```